# Mysql search query with AND operator: filtering out null parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search query build with OR, but I'd like to use the same with AND to get less results. Unfortunatly, as some parameters (VatStatut, VarDomaine, etc.) are left empty in the input form, I get no results at all. How can I filter out these null parameters?

```
$VarStatut_jeu_res1 = "%";
if (isset($_POST['choix_statut'])) {
$VarStatut_jeu_res1 = $_POST['choix_statut'];
}

$VarSujet_jeu_res1 = "%";
if (isset($_POST['choix_sujet'])) {
$VarSujet_jeu_res1 = $_POST['choix_sujet'];
}

$VarDateEcheance1_jeu_res1 = "%";
if (isset($_POST['choix_dateecheance1'])) {
$VarDateEcheance1_jeu_res1 = $_POST['choix_dateecheance1'];
}

$VarDateEcheance2_jeu_res1 = "%";
if (isset($_POST['choix_dateecheance2'])) {
$VarDateEcheance2_jeu_res1 = $_POST['choix_dateecheance2'];
}

$VarDateOrigine1_jeu_res1 = "%";
if (isset($_POST['choix_dateorigine1'])) {
$VarDateOrigine1_jeu_res1 = $_POST['choix_dateorigine1'];
}

$VarDateOrigine2_jeu_res1 = "%";
if (isset($_POST['choix_dateorigine2'])) {
$VarDateOrigine2_jeu_res1 = $_POST['choix_dateorigine2'];
}

$VarTheme_jeu_res1 = "%";
if (isset($_POST['choix_theme'])) {
$VarTheme_jeu_res1 = $_POST['choix_theme'];
}

$VarAuteur_jeu_res1 = "%";
if (isset($_POST['choix_auteur'])) {
$VarAuteur_jeu_res1 = $_POST['choix_auteur'];
}

$VarDomaine_jeu_res1 = "%";
if (isset($_POST['choix_domaine'])) {
$VarDomaine_jeu_res1 = $_POST['choix_domaine'];
}

mysql_select_db($database_ConnJournal, $ConnJournal);

$query_jeu_res1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Projets1 WHERE Projets1.Statut LIKE %s OR       Projets1.Domaine LIKE %s OR Projets1.Auteur LIKE %s OR Projets1.Theme LIKE %s OR Projets1.DateOrigine BETWEEN %s AND %s OR Projets1.DateEcheance BETWEEN %s AND %s OR MATCH (Sujet) AGAINST (%s) ORDER BY Projets1.DateHeure DESC",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `empty()` instead of `isset`. This way if the variable exists but is the empty string the parameter wont be set.

I.e.

```
$VarDomaine_jeu_res1 = "%";
if (!empty($_POST['choix_domaine'])) {
    $VarDomaine_jeu_res1 = $_POST['choix_domaine'];
}
```

(Note we are using `!empty()`)